# What does this command Actually do? Is it correct?

Tags: bash, find, command

I found this command line when I was checking a Bash Script! My question is what does this command do and is this command correct?

```
    find / -name "*.src" | xargs cp ~/Desktop/Log.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

find the files or directory with `.src` extension in `/` and copy file `~/Desktop/Log.txt` as the find result's filename

for example if the output of the find command is

```
file.src
directory1.src
file2.src
```

`xargs` command will execute `cp ~/Desktop/Log.txt file.src directory1.src  file2.src` which does not make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

**What the command is**

```
find / -name "*.src"
```

*Explanation:* Recursively find all regular files, directories, and symlinks in `/`, for which the filename ends in `.src`

```
|
```

*Explanation:* Redirect stdout from the command on the left side of the pipe  to stdin of the command on the right side

```
xargs cp ~/Desktop/Log.txt
```

*Explanation:* Build a `cp` command, taking arguments from stdin and appending them into a space-delimited list at the end of the command. If the pre-defined buffer space of `xargs` (generally bounded by `ARG_MAX`) is exhausted multiple `cp` commands will be executed,

e.g. `xargs cp arg100 .... arg900` could be processed as `cp a100 ... a500; cp a501 ... a900`

**Note** The behavior of your `cp` varies a lot depending on its arguments

- If `~/Desktop/Log.txt` is the only argument, `cp` will throw stderr
- If the last argument to `cp` is a directory

  - All preceding arguments that are regular files will be copied into it
  - Nothing will happen for all preceding arguments that are directories, except stderr will be thrown
- If the last argument is a regular file

  - If there are 2 total arguments to `cp` and the first one is a regular file. Then the contents of the second argument file will be overwritten by the contents of the first argument
  - If there are more than 2 total arguments, `cp` will throw a stderr

So all in all, there are too many variables here for the behavior of your command to really ever be precisely defined. As such, I suspect, you wanted to do something else.

**What it probably should have been**

My guess is the author of the command probably wanted to redirect stdout to a log file (note the log file will be overwritten each time you run the command)

```
find / -name "*.src" > ~/Desktop/Log.txt
```

Additionally, if you are just looking for regular files with the `.src` extension, you should also add the `-type f` option to `find`

```
find / -type f -name "*.src" > ~/Desktop/Log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

It finds every file or directory that match the pattern `*.src` from `/`.

Then copy the file `~/Desktop/Log.txt` to every result of previous command.